# Flutter: Custom name for screenshot image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following the following flutter package to take a screenshot of my one app page:

https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

I have successfully implemented the example and I can see my screenshots in the gallery.

My issue is that I would like to be able to NAME those images when they are stored in the gallery using some sort of numbering system. e.g. INV_0001, INV_0002.

Is there a way to do this in code? I have the following code that successfully takes the screenshot, but does not rename the file.

**CODE**

```
_imageGallerySaver() async {
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path; //from path_provide package
    String fileName = "Bob";
    String pathName = '$directory/$fileName.png';

    //print(path);
    screenshotController
        .capture(
      path: pathName,
    ).then((File image) async {
      print("image: $image");
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
      });
      print(pathName);
      final result =
      await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image.readAsBytesSync());
      print("File Saved to Gallery. result: $result");
      //print("path: $path");
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  }
```

**SNIPPET**

```
print("File Saved to Gallery. result: $result");
```

results in the following output:

```
File Saved to Gallery. result: file:///storage/emulated/0/app_name/1581602261670.png
```

I would like to rename the "1581602261670" part, if possible. Thank you

Comment: Use this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/rename.html

Comment: Where would I place that in my code, please? It doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Actually that filename is passed by yourself, simply change it as you wish

Comment: @Darish I can't get it to work with rename or using the path name. It always comes out as a random "number.png". Could you please show me how you would do it on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't rename files using this method. Need to use a package called Gallery Saver:
 https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

This package allows you to set your own file name and save to the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are passing that file name to construct the path, then why not change the name there itself.

Anyway, you can rename an existing file using

await file.rename (newPath
):

Comment: I like that there's a method called "rename", but it doesn't appear to do anything to the name of my image in the gallery. Where would I place this in my current code?

Comment: Check whether your file existing or not using the given path by that package, if yes you can rename it using the rename function.

Comment: "In your code, you are passing that file name to construct the path, then why not change the name there itself."

I am changing the name there if you look closely. I'm adding the word "Bob" onto it as a test, but it's not working. And it seems neither is this rename method. I have a feeling it has to do with that "ImageGallerySaver.saveImage" part. All my files get names with some random number.png

Comment: Then open am issue on their git repo so that they can fix it